# How to write xpath if element has no unique 'accessibility id' in Appium IOS Xcuit Test

Tags: appium-ios

How to handle elements which does not have unique accessibility id's
Please find the below link for screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **avoid using XPath** with **Appium on iOS**: it's **not natively supported by XCUTest** and because of it, significantly affects performance of elements search.

Second, it would be nice to set accessibility label even it will be a group of elements with the same one:

Here is a Java sample how you can search and select one of the elements with same id:

```
        List<WebElement> elsWithSameId = driver.findElements(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("your id"));
        WebElement specificElement = elsWithSameId.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getText() == "My Favorite element")
            .findFirst()
            .get();
        specificElement.click();
```

If you still want to use XPath, just try to find more/less unique class for the elements you want to interact with, then build [iOS predicates](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) (similar mechanism to XPath, but its native to XCUITest)

Comment: Hi this is my element accessibility id 'DNEX' and xpath is '//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="DNEX"]' here 'DNEX' was might vary for every execution in this type of scenario how we can handle the elements could you please help me.